# Password change event behaviour not working properly in prism using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am triggering password change event and command action
**xaml**

```
 <PasswordBox VmWindow:PasswordHelper.Attach="True" Height="25" Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" BorderBrush="#FF959BA0" TabIndex="2"
                             VmWindow:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangePasswordCommand}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                </PasswordBox>
```

**Password changed event code:**

```
 private static void PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
            SetIsUpdating(passwordBox, true);
            SetPassword(passwordBox, passwordBox.Password);
            SetIsUpdating(passwordBox, false);
        }
```

**Command Action**

```
public ICommand ChangePasswordCommand { get; private set; }
        public LoginViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        private void ExecuteChangePasswordCommand()
        {
            try
            {
                if (loginModel != null)
                {
                    loginModel.LoginPassword = Password;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }

        }
```

**Problem:**

What is happening intially when application loads i enter char in textbox the "Event fires first and then action which ok normal senario",but when i press second char "my Action fires first then trigger that is the problem"

I don't know weather it is predefined process or am i doing something wrong .Because according to me order should always **Event,action** not **Action,event**

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after spending a lot of time i am able to solve the above problem with some additional changes

Add Reference of `Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions`

Add two refrences:

```
xmlns:i="clrnamespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions
```

Done few changes in password box:

```
<PasswordBox VmWindow:PasswordHelper.Attach="True" Height="25" Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" BorderBrush="#FF959BA0" TabIndex="2"
                             VmWindow:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="changePassword"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>


                </PasswordBox>
```

**Create a Method in Your LoginViewModel**

```
 public void changePassword(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
            loginModel.LoginPassword = passwordBox.Password;
        }
```

Done With changes its clean MVVM with no code behind now